# Form Validation with If Else statements and document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I'm new to the site but I have spent the last week trawling the internet for an answer to this and I can't seem to find one.

What I want is 2 out of 3 fields in a form to validate when clicking the submit button, and instead of going to the next page, it needs to validate before allowing that.

This is what I have,

HTML:

```js
function validateForm(input) {
  var isValid = true;
  if (!document.getElementById("Name").value.trim().length) {
    isValid = false;
    alert("Please enter your First Name");
  } else if (!document.getElementById("Comment1").value.trim().length) {
    isvalid = false;
    alert("Please enter your phone number");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  if (isValid) {
    document.getElementById('ICContainer').style.display;
    loadInstantChat();
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=submit] {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 322px;
  background-color: #EF423E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-decoration: double;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text],
[type=number],
[type=email] {
  width: 323px;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid #EF423E 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #4E4E56;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<body onload="handleRebootOrRefresh();">
  <form name="input" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm(input)" method="post">
    Your first name:* <input id="Name" type="text" name="inputName"> Your phone number:* <input id="Comment1" type="text" name="inputNumber"> Claim Reference: <input id="Comment2" type="text" name="inputClaim">
    <input type="submit" value="Chat Now" onclick="validateForm(input)">
  </form>

  <div id="ICContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 350px; height: 550px; display: none"></div>
</body>
```

There's a lot of other JavaScript running in this code that I don't want to touch, but I do need to know how to get the top 2 fields to validate and if it successfully validates, it processes to the next page (i.e. `document.getElementByID('ICContainer').style.display; loadInstantChat();`

To make it clear, this is a LogMeIn Rescue instant chat instance and their support line is "Don't touch anything, even though we literally give you a step-by-step guide".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of the function to prevent the form submission

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

and function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have attempted this. I can get the validation to work, but I can't get it to work that after validation, it calls document.getElementById('ICContainer').style.display;
    loadInstantChat();

Comment: `I can get the validation to work, but I can't get it to work that after validation` clarify?

Comment: So the two forms that I required validated, the name and phone number come up with an alert stating that the boxes are required. If the boxes are correctly filled out, no alert pops up, but it doesn't open up the next document/run the next script.

Comment: Going to be honest, it's very complicated as I'm working with another companies code, and a lot of what happens is hidden in an external JS file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove some attributes from your form balise:

```
action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm(input)" method="post"
```

You can create a new function (handleForm) that call validateForm and if everythings it's ok send an AJAX Request to your server.

```
<input type="submit" value="Chat Now" onclick="handleForm(input)">

[...]
function handleForm(input) {
  var isValid = validateForm(input);
  if (isValid) {
    //perform your ajax request here
  }
}

function validateForm(input) { ...
```